# subtracting two values inside a list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, subtraction

```
my_list = [['chr1', 65419, 65433], ['chr1', 65520, 65573], ['chr1', 69037, 71585], ['chr1', 69055, 70108], ['chr1', 137621, 139379],['chr2', 65419, 65433], ['chr2', 65520, 65573], ['chr2', 69037, 71585], ['chr3', 69055, 70108]]
```

Inside the lists, there will be strings as 'chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3'. I want to subtract the values of index 2-1 of each string, and get the total value for 'chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3'

example
In the first two strings (65433 - 65419) should get subtract and this should get added to the (65573-65520) because both contains 'chr1'. This should happen for all the lists and final results should be as follows
'chr1' total = x_value, 'chr2' total = y_value, 'chr3' total = x_value

I'm kind of new python.can somebody suggest a code for this.

Comment: is there really just 3 unique strings?

Comment: No there are many more, I have just put  3 unique strings. there will be atleast 30.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = [['chr1', 65419, 65433], ['chr1', 65520, 65573], ['chr1', 69037, 71585], ['chr1', 69055, 70108], ['chr1', 137621, 139379],['chr2', 65419, 65433], ['chr2', 65520, 65573], ['chr2', 69037, 71585], ['chr3', 69055, 70108]]
mylist1=list()
mylist2=list()
mylist3=list()

for i in my_list:
    if i[0]=='chr1':
        mylist1.append(i[2]-i[1])
    elif i[0]=='chr2':
        mylist2.append(i[2]-i[1])
    elif i[0]=='chr3':
        mylist3.append(i[2]-i[1])

print("chr1:",sum(mylist1))
print("chr2:",sum(mylist2))
print("chr3:",sum(mylist3))
```

sum is already predefined function to use.

now if you have more chr:

```
my_list = [['chr1', 65419, 65433], ['chr1', 65520, 65573], ['chr1', 69037, 71585], ['chr1', 69055, 70108], ['chr1', 137621, 139379],['chr2', 65419, 65433], ['chr2', 65520, 65573], ['chr2', 69037, 71585], ['chr3', 69055, 70108]]
chrset=set()
for i in my_list:
    chrset.add(i[0])

res = dict.fromkeys(chrset, 0)

for i in my_list:
    res[i[0]]=res[i[0]]+i[2]-i[1]
print(res)
```

its lot more easier for one who is new in python, just making a set of chr1,chr2,.... then creating a dictionary and doing operation on it directly.

Answer (score 2):

For large lists, you can do (no hard-coded string matches):

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [['chr1', 65419, 65433], ['chr1', 65520, 65573], ['chr1', 69037, 71585], ['chr1', 69055, 70108], ['chr1', 137621, 139379],['chr2', 65419, 65433], ['chr2', 65520, 65573], ['chr2', 69037, 71585], ['chr3', 69055, 70108]]

f = lambda x: x[0]
for k, g in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=f), key=f):
    print(k, sum(x[2] - x[1] for x in g))

# chr1 5426
# chr2 2615
# chr3 1053
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
my_list = [['chr1', 65419, 65433], ['chr1', 65520, 65573], ['chr1', 69037, 71585], ['chr1', 69055, 70108], ['chr1', 137621, 139379],['chr2', 65419, 65433], ['chr2', 65520, 65573], ['chr2', 69037, 71585], ['chr3', 69055, 70108]]
result = defaultdict(int)
temp = [{i[0]:i[2]-i[1]} for i in my_list]
for di in temp:
    result [ list(di.keys())[0] ] += list(di.values())[0]
for i,v in result.items():
    print(f"{i} total = {v}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to hold key  -value pairs, and update them as you have more lists with the same key.

```
my_dict=dict()
for entry in my_list:
    if entry[0] in my_dict:
        my_dict[entry[0]]+=entry[2]-entry[1]
     else:
         my_dict [entry[0]]=entry[2]-entry[1]
```

This works whatever keys you have (not limited to the three in your example)